# Sum of algebraic number of prime degree.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, algebraic-numbers

I'm looking to prove the following:

Let $K$ be a field and suppose that $[K(\alpha):K]=p$ and $[K(\beta):K]=q$ for $p,q$ distinct primes. Then $K(\alpha+\beta):K$ has degree $pq$.

Of course I know that $K(\alpha+\beta)$ has either degree $1,p,q$ or $pq$ over $K$. But I do not know how to rule out the cases where the degree is $p$ or $q$. Is there another way?

Comment: That requires that $K(\alpha+\beta)$ contains $K(\alpha)$, in which case we would have that $K(\alpha+\beta)=K(\alpha,\beta)$. However, such an argument would need to use the fact that $p$ and $q$ are prime, since this is not true in general.

Comment: This is not true when $K$ has positive characteristic, see the comment and proof I made there.